# Javascript: download image once, set it as src or background to several objects

Tags: javascript, image, performance

I am trying to understand how to minimize network traffic on my site.  If I create an Image object, set its src to a url and then set another Image object's src to the original Image object's src in its onload handler, would that result in one network call to download the image or 2?

Reading Stackoverflow leads me to believe that it would lead to 1 call because the image would get cached.  However, here is a jsfiddle where I've disabled cache in Chrome dev tools and there's still only one network call to download the image.  https://jsfiddle.net/oe7vdo30/

```
<div id='background' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;'>
</div>

<img id='image' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid green;'/>


var div = document.getElementById("background");
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
   $(div).css("background-image", "url("+imageObj.src+")");  
   image.src = imageObj.src;
};
imageObj.src =     "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/62/Riscos_logo_generic_cogwheel_richard_hallas_lg_cogwheel_x1.svg/512px-Riscos_logo_generic_cogwheel_richard_hallas_lg_cogwheel_x1.svg.png";
```

That's good news to me but I don't understand why it works like that. Also, as you can see in the jsfiddle, I'm trying to set a DIV element's background-image url to the Image object's src, which also does not add another network call.

So my question is this: why is there only one network call to download an image in my code above, even though I've disabled cache in Chrome dev tools?

Thanks!

Comment: This is total conjecture from me but I think that for a single request to a webpage, it would be horribly inefficient to download the same image multiple times. So it still caches the image (even with the setting turned off) for a single request.

Comment: Wonder if it's true across browsers.  I agree that it is horribly inefficient to have the image downloaded 3 times in my code above, but I'd like to fully understand where the optimization is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will only fetch a static asset **at a specific URI** one time and will reuse that asset when necessary. The caching that you disabled would come in to play when you reload the page (you are telling Chrome not to store the image locally and to always fetch the asset over the network). If you add a query string parameter to the image URL for your `image` variable, another request will be made because the asset now has a different URI (even though it is the exact same image): https://jsfiddle.net/hvn6r9re/

Comment: Thank you! Is it safe assume that the same mechanism works the same way in different browsers?

Comment: My pleasure! You can expect this behavior from modern browsers in most cases - though there are edge cases where the image may download twice (an XHR request for the image resource, for instance [read more](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1075297) )